# Can't upgrade Windows Server 2012 Essentials to Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials

Tags: essentials-2012, windows-server-essentials, essentials-2012-r2

So today was [RTM of Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials released](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevengu/archive/2013/09/09/download-windows-8-1-rtm-visual-studio-2013-rc-and-windows-server-2012-r2-rtm-today.aspx).
I immediately tried to do an in-place upgrade of an existing RTM 2012 Essentials to RTM 2012 R2 Essentials, but get:

> Windows Server 2012 Essentials cannot be upgraded to Windows Server
>   2012 R2 Essentials. You can choose to install a new copy of Windows
>   Server 2012 R2 Essentials instead, but this is different from an
>   upgrade, and does not keep your files, settings, and programs. You’ll
>   need to reinstall any programs using the original installation discs
>   or files. To save your files before installing Windows, back them up
>   to an external location such as a CD, DVD, or external hard drive. To
>   install a new copy of Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials, click the
>   Back button in the upper left-hand corner, and select “Custom
>   (advanced)”.

This seems a bit odd, is this really the case? I can't find anything in the official documentation stating that this upgrade isn't possible.

Comment: Unless I missed something pretty big, 2012 R2 Essentials RTM has *not* been released. Are you sure you're not trying to install the preview, which would be bad in a production environment.

Comment: Yes I am sure and you are correct, you have missed something. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevengu/archive/2013/09/09/download-windows-8-1-rtm-visual-studio-2013-rc-and-windows-server-2012-r2-rtm-today.aspx

Comment: Well, that is good news, since MS had been silent on early release info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't appear that an in-place upgrade is available, rather you need to migrate.  Same as in SBS 2011 to 2012 Essentials.

See here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/41695fc1-6e0c-4218-bb7a-0984e54d5ce5/will-i-be-able-to-upgrade-or-migrate-my-current-windows-server-2012-essentials-installation-once-r2

> No inplace upgrade.
>
> You will need to migrate from 2012 to 2012 r2 by installing R2 in
>   migration mode and copying data/can't copy backups over,
>   decommissioning the old box.

and "official" Microsoft Technet article here: [Migrate from Previous Versions to Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn408633.aspx)

Comment: Oh well, sad panda. :(

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Server Essentials, upgrade is not supported. Migration would be recommended.

Best Regards,
Eve Wang

Comment: Hello, could you please provide source/reference?